# Getting an anchor value which is inside a li tag

Tags: javascript

I have the this code:

```
<li class="email">
    <a href="mailto:abc@gmail.com">abc@gmail.com</a>
</li>
```

I would like to get the `abc@gmail.com` using **plain JavaScript**

I though of doing `document.getElementsByTagName("email")` which gives me the above, but I don't have an idea how to continue.

I have managed to find a solution with the help of the below answer by a user

```
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.email');
var email = elem[0].children[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.email');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    var elem = elems[i];
    console.log(elem.firstElementChild.getAttribute('href').substr(7));
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/Cx2VY/

However, `document.querySelectorAll` is not available in all browsers. Some have `document.getElementsByClassName)` which would also work for you. But other browsers have neither. Consider adding [**Sizzle**](http://sizzlejs.com/) if you don't want jQuery etc. It is the selector engine used by jQuery and other libs and takes away the burden of handling the cross-browser stuff from you.

When using `querySelectorAll` or Sizzle, you could make your code even easier by removing `.firstChild` and using the selector `.email > a` instead.

Comment: Something wrong here, document.querySelectorAll('.email'); gives you back the <li class="email">
    <a href="mailto:abc@gmail.com">abc@gmail.com</a>
</li>

Comment: `firstChild` will return the first *node* child, not element child. Thus, it's probably a `textNode` that will be returned, not having an `href` attribute. `firstElementChild` solves this problem. See the updated jsfiddle that conforms to OP's example, it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/Cx2VY/1/

Comment: His markup did not contain whitespace inside the `<li>` initially. But well, there we have another reason to use a library! Is `firstElementChild` cross-browser?

Comment: Starting IE9, just like `querySelectorAll` (buggy in IE8).

Answer (score 1):

I there is a mistake on your code, that should be like this to get the "a" element

```
var email=document.getElementsByClassName('email')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
```

now you have the email object, then you can process the rest using email oblject like this

```
 alert(email.innerHTML); // will print abc@gmail.com
```

Comment: Be careful, this doesn't work. The following would work: `document.getElementsByClassName('email')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];`, but this'd only get the first `email` class.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a cross browser solution? How much cross-browser?

Modern browser only solution would be:

```
[].forEach.call( document.getElementsByClassName( 'email' ), function( el ) {
    console.log( el.firstElementChild.textContent );
} );
```

Using `children[0]` makes you crawl the children of the element, while `firstElementChild` only gets the first element child (and not node child, since a space is a node child and you don't want that).

`forEach`, `getElementsByClassName`, `textContent`, `firstElementChild` or even `querySelectorAll` are not cross-browser (don't work in legacy browsers).

But since you want to use `querySelectorAll`, that means you're supporting IE9 at least (since it's buggy in IE8 and not implemented in IE7). IE9 supports all the method quoted above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more cross-browser:

```
function getElsByClassName(classname){
    var rv = []; 
    var elems  = document.getElementsByTagName('*')
    if (elems.length){
        for (var x in elems ){
            if (elems[x] && elems[x].className && elems[x].className == classname){
                rv.push(elems[x]);
            }
        }
    }
    return rv; 
}

//Get the li
var li = getElsByClassName("email"); //Alass, it returns an array
var a = li[0].firstChild; 
var email = a.getAttribute('href').substr(7);
```

Comment: Horrible performance though as it *always* iterates the whole DOM even if better functions are available. However, that's why I suggested sizzle - it is pretty stupid to refuse using a highly optimized small library just because you want to write everything on your own.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I just posted it because you mentioned the cross-browser issue. This is what a quick googling brings. I never said it's a good solution, but with IE it may prove worthful to have a function that is very cross-browser.