# Whats wrong with this my javascript code ? it is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="abcd"></div>
<style>
.new_info {
color:red;
}
</style>
<script>

function getBox(){
    var sende = document.querySelectorAll(".abcd");

    alert(sende[0].hasChildNodes());
    alert(y[0].hasChildNodes());
    if(sende[0].hasChildNodes() == false && sende[0].nodeValue == null){
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.innerHTML = "which i want";
            newdiv.className = "new_info";
            sende[0].appendChild(newdiv);
}
}
getBox();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In above code i want to fill div tag having class 'abcd' with some div as childnode having some text like 'which i want'. this work well in other browser but not in IE8.
what should i do to work this code in IE8 too ?

Comment: what this code is doing `alert(y[0].hasChildNodes());` because of this it is not executing in IE8

Comment: See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/NmFNH/ i have commented `alert(y[0].hasChildNodes());` and it is working fine..

Answer (score 2):

The `querySelectorAll` does not work in IE8 eg only works only in **IE8 standards mode** and there are [bug reports](http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-internetexplorer-general/471117-bug-ie8s-queryselectorall-implementation.html) of it when it comes to IE8.

For solution check out:

- [Cross Browser `getElementsByClassName`](http://code.google.com/p/getelementsbyclassname/)

Sadly or luckily because of these cross browser issues, there exist JavaScript libraries to benefit from which clear all that mess for us internally.

Comment: than what is the solution for this ?

Comment: is there any alternative of querySelectorAll ?

Comment: @AhsanRathod: Yep but it only works in IE8 Stadards mood and is buggy in IE8

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName is also not working so what else that works for IE8?

Comment: @AhsanRathod: Also check:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426773/getting-an-anchor-value-which-is-inside-a-li-tag

Answer (score 0):

What this code is doing `alert(y[0].hasChildNodes());` in your code, because of this it is not executing.

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/NmFNH

i have commented `alert(y[0].hasChildNodes());` and it is working.